# How to replace missing values in a column with ndarray/model prediction

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, scikit-learn

I would like to use the model prediction (lets say `RandomForestRegression`) to replace the missing value in the column `Age` of a dataframe. I checked that the data type of the model prediction is `numpy.ndarray`.

Here’s what I do:

```
a = RandomForestRegressor()
a.fit(train_data, target)
result = a.predict(test_data)
df[df.Age.isna()].Age.iloc[:] = result
```

But it doesn’t work and can’t replace the `nan` value. May I ask why?

I saw some people use the same method but they work.

Comment: Try `df.loc[df['Age'].isna(), 'Age'] = result.values`. If this doesn't work, then your `result` values are not the same shape as the null values in `df['Age']`. This means your logic is unclear.

Comment: I used `df.loc[df['Age'].isna(), 'Age'] = result` and it worked. May I ask why do you use `result.values`? Since the predication value of should be an array but not dictionary. Thank you so much!

Comment: `result.values` has nothing to do with `dict`. It just uses `pd.Series.values` to use the NumPy array for assignment. If the answer below solves your problem, please accept it (green tick on left) so other users know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use chained indexing. It is [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) in the docs. The inconsistency you may be seeing may be linked to copy versus view discrepancies as described in the docs.

Instead, use a single [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) call:

```
df.loc[df['Age'].isna(), 'Age'] = result
```

See also [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).