# Pandas - Fill in Missing Column Values Regression

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I have a data frame 'df' that has missing column values. I want to fill in the missing/NaN values in the `Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges` column through prediction (regression) using the other column values. Then, replace the NaN values with the new values found.

Data frame: 'df'

```
Customer ID,Gender,Age,Married,Number of Dependents,City,Zip Code,Latitude,Longitude,Number of Referrals,Tenure in Months,Offer,Phone Service,Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges,Multiple Lines,Internet Service,Internet Type,Avg Monthly GB Download,Online Security,Online Backup,Device Protection Plan,Premium Tech Support,Streaming TV,Streaming Movies,Streaming Music,Unlimited Data,Contract,Paperless Billing,Payment Method,Monthly Charge,Total Charges,Total Refunds,Total Extra Data Charges,Total Long Distance Charges,Total Revenue,Customer Status,Churn Category,Churn Reason
0002-ORFBO,Female,37,Yes,0,Frazier Park,93225,34.827662,-118.999073,2,9,None,Yes,42.39,No,Yes,Cable,16,No,Yes,No,Yes,Yes,No,No,Yes,One Year,Yes,Credit Card,65.6,593.3,0,0,381.51,974.81,Stayed,,
0003-MKNFE,Male,46,No,0,Glendale,91206,34.162515,-118.203869,0,9,None,Yes,10.69,Yes,Yes,Cable,10,No,No,No,No,No,Yes,Yes,No,Month-to-Month,No,Credit Card,-4,542.4,38.33,10,96.21,610.28,Stayed,,
0004-TLHLJ,Male,50,No,0,Costa Mesa,92627,33.645672,-117.922613,0,4,Offer E,Yes,33.65,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,30,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,73.9,280.85,0,0,134.6,415.45,Churned,Competitor,Competitor had better devices
0011-IGKFF,Male,78,Yes,0,Martinez,94553,38.014457,-122.115432,1,13,Offer D,Yes,27.82,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,4,No,Yes,Yes,No,Yes,Yes,No,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,98,1237.85,0,0,361.66,1599.51,Churned,Dissatisfaction,Product dissatisfaction
0013-EXCHZ,Female,75,Yes,0,Camarillo,93010,34.227846,-119.079903,3,3,None,Yes,7.38,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,11,No,No,No,Yes,Yes,No,No,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Credit Card,83.9,267.4,0,0,22.14,289.54,Churned,Dissatisfaction,Network reliability
0013-MHZWF,Female,23,No,3,Midpines,95345,37.581496,-119.972762,0,9,Offer E,Yes,16.77,No,Yes,Cable,73,No,No,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Credit Card,69.4,571.45,0,0,150.93,722.38,Stayed,,
0013-SMEOE,Female,67,Yes,0,Lompoc,93437,34.757477,-120.550507,1,71,Offer A,Yes,9.96,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,14,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,109.7,7904.25,0,0,707.16,8611.41,Stayed,,
0014-BMAQU,Male,52,Yes,0,Napa,94558,38.489789,-122.27011,8,63,Offer B,Yes,12.96,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,7,Yes,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Two Year,Yes,Credit Card,84.65,5377.8,0,20,816.48,6214.28,Stayed,,
0015-UOCOJ,Female,68,No,0,Simi Valley,93063,34.296813,-118.685703,0,7,Offer E,Yes,10.53,No,Yes,DSL,21,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,No,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,48.2,340.35,0,0,73.71,414.06,Stayed,,
0016-QLJIS,Female,43,Yes,1,Sheridan,95681,38.984756,-121.345074,3,65,None,Yes,28.46,Yes,Yes,Cable,14,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Credit Card,90.45,5957.9,0,0,1849.9,7807.8,Stayed,,
0017-DINOC,Male,47,No,0,Rancho Santa Fe,92091,32.99356,-117.207121,0,54,None,No,,,Yes,Cable,10,Yes,No,No,Yes,Yes,No,No,Yes,Two Year,No,Credit Card,45.2,2460.55,0,0,0,2460.55,Stayed,,
0017-IUDMW,Female,25,Yes,2,Sunnyvale,94086,37.378541,-122.020456,2,72,None,Yes,16.01,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,59,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Credit Card,116.8,8456.75,0,0,1152.72,9609.47,Stayed,,
0018-NYROU,Female,58,Yes,0,Antelope,95843,38.715498,-121.363411,0,5,None,Yes,18.65,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,10,No,No,No,No,No,No,No,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,68.95,351.5,0,0,93.25,444.75,Stayed,,
0019-EFAEP,Female,32,No,0,La Mesa,91942,32.782501,-117.01611,0,72,Offer A,Yes,2.25,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,16,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,Yes,No,No,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,101.3,7261.25,0,0,162,7423.25,Stayed,,
0019-GFNTW,Female,39,No,0,Los Olivos,93441,34.70434,-120.02609,0,56,None,No,,,Yes,DSL,19,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,Yes,Two Year,No,Bank Withdrawal,45.05,2560.1,0,0,0,2560.1,Stayed,,
0020-INWCK,Female,58,Yes,2,Woodlake,93286,36.464635,-119.094348,9,71,Offer A,Yes,27.26,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,12,No,Yes,Yes,No,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Credit Card,95.75,6849.4,0,0,1935.46,8784.86,Stayed,,
0020-JDNXP,Female,52,Yes,1,Point Reyes Station,94956,38.060264,-122.830646,0,34,None,No,,,Yes,DSL,20,Yes,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,One Year,No,Credit Card,61.25,1993.2,0,0,0,1993.2,Stayed,,
0021-IKXGC,Female,72,No,0,San Marcos,92078,33.119028,-117.166036,0,1,Offer E,Yes,7.77,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,22,No,No,No,No,No,No,No,Yes,One Year,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,72.1,72.1,0,0,7.77,79.87,Joined,,
0022-TCJCI,Male,79,No,0,Daly City,94015,37.680844,-122.48131,0,45,None,Yes,10.67,No,Yes,DSL,17,Yes,No,Yes,No,No,Yes,No,Yes,One Year,No,Credit Card,62.7,2791.5,0,0,480.15,3271.65,Churned,Dissatisfaction,Limited range of services
```

My code:

```
# Let X = predictor variable and y = target variable
X = pd.DataFrame(df[['Monthly Charge', 'Total Charges', 'Total Long Distance Charges']])
y = pd.DataFrame(df[['Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges']])

# Add a constant variable to the predictor variables
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model01 = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
df['Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges'].fillna(sm.OLS(y, X).fit())
```

My code output:

```
0                                                   42.39
1                                                   10.69
2                                                   33.65
3                                                   27.82
4                                                    7.38
                              ...                        
7038                                                46.68
7039                                                 16.2
7040                                                18.62
7041                                                 2.12
7042    <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.Regressio...
Name: Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges, Length: 7043, dtype: object
```

My code outputs this, but does not print this into the original data frame. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can just set the column equal to your new output. Or you can add the `inplace=True` method when filling missing values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace missing values in a column with ndarray/model prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606360/how-to-replace-missing-values-in-a-column-with-ndarray-model-prediction)

Comment: @m13op22 Is it something like this? `df['Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges'].replace(np.nan, df['Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges'].fillna(sm.OLS(y, X).fit()), inplace=True)`

Comment: Did that work? Assuming the other outcomes stay the same, I was thinking all you'd have to do is `df['column name'] = df['column name'].fillna(sm.OLS(y, X).fit())`